Unable to inject properties using Value annotation in feign client configuration
I am creating feign clients using configuration as I am creating custom retryer for the API and I am using @Value annotation to inject the properties but the properties are not getting injected, however if I use the same property in another class then the property is getting injected to that class. Also I cannot put @Configuration annotation on configuration class as I need to configure different settings for different feign clients.
@FeignClient(name = "searchClient",
        configuration = SearchEndPointConfig.class)
public interface SearchFeignClient {
}

public class SearchEndPointConfig {
    private static final Notifier NOTIFIER = Notifier.getNotifier(MarginSearchEndPointConfig.class);

    @Value("${search.connect.timeout.seconds}")
    private Integer connectionTimeOut; --> Value populates is null

    @Value("${search.read.timeout.seconds}")
    private Integer readTimeOut;

    @Value("${search.retry.max}")
    private Integer maxRetries;

    @Value("${search.retry.initial.delay.seconds}")
    private Integer initialDelay;

    @Value("${search.retry.internal.delay.seconds}")
    private Integer retryInterval;

    @Bean
    public Retryer retryer() {
        return new SearchRetryer(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(initialDelay), TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(retryInterval), maxRetries);
    }
    
    //other config
}

@Service 
public class SearchLevelRule implements RuleRunner {
    @Value("${search.connect.timeout.seconds}")
    private Integer connectionTimeOut; --> Value is populated correctly

    //Rest of code
}

